# oracle table is not listing in the Toad schema browser for the particular schema

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a table named TableA in oracle 11g database, i could able to select this table by using the particular user id in toad, but i dont find this table in the toad schema browser for that schema in the toad.  please advice me on why i couldnt able to find that table in the schema browser or how to find that table?. Let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Can be a View.
Can be a public synonym to table in another schema.

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> mouse button on table name in your query to go to object details.